# How can I remove a pattern from a string in SQL on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently have this SQL stored procedure:

```
    DECLARE @old nvarchar(MAX)
    SELECT @old = ReadPostIds FROM CrmUserDetails  WHERE MemberNumber = @memNum

     UPDATE CrmUserDetails SET ReadPostIds = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),REPLACE(@old,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @postId), '') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @postId) + ',' )
     WHERE MemberNumber = @memNum
```

Instead of 1,2,3, etc I'd like to add a pipe to each comma deliminated element and another number like 1|2,3|4,5|6 etc.

The problem with this is that I don't know what the second number will be. So where I do this:

```
 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),REPLACE(@old,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @postId), '')
```

I'd like to do this:

```
 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),REPLACE(@old,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @postId) + * + '|', '')
```

Where * is anything. I know that the solution will be something to do with PATINDEX() but my deadline was yesterday, I've worked for 16 hours and am terrible at SQL.

Any helpe would be great.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Can you show us a few strings with expected results? like `Before`, `After`

Comment: Sure, before:

1|2,2|3,4|5555

After replacing 2|*,

1|2,4|5555

Comment: Anyone? It would be the equivelant to Regex.Replace(strIn, @"1\|\d+\,", string.Empty); in C#. Gonna get some sleep now, gnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this as an example:

```
DECLARE @old nvarchar(MAX), @pattern nvarchar(20), @replace nvarchar(20)
SELECT @old = ReadPostIds FROM CrmUserDetails  WHERE MemberNumber = @memNum

SET @pattern = L'%2|_%' -- Note how the pattern must be declared, the actual searched string in the pattern is 2|*, as per your example
SET @replace = L''

WHILE PATINDEX(@pattern, @old) > 0
BEGIN
    @old = STUFF(@old, PATINDEX(@pattern, @old), LEN(@pattern)-2, @replace)
END 

UPDATE CrmUserDetails SET ReadPostIds = @old
WHERE MemberNumber = @memNum
```

I recommend creating a function for the WHILE loop and use it straight away, like this:

```
UPDATE CrmUserDetails SET ReadPostIds = dbo.udfReplacePattern(ReadPostIds, '%2|_%', '')
WHERE MemberNumber = @memNum
```

Comment: pattern recognition is a regular expression problem.  Why isn't there an more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cha response but with SQL server format and with an example:

```
DECLARE @old nvarchar(MAX), @pattern nvarchar(20), @replace nvarchar(20)
SELECT @old = '0,1,2'

SET @pattern = '%,%' 
SET @replace = '|'

select PATINDEX(@pattern, @old)
WHILE PATINDEX(@pattern, @old) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @old = STUFF(@old, PATINDEX(@pattern, @old), LEN(@pattern)-2, @replace)
END 

SELECT @old
```